# How to examine if there is termite damage in a ceiling or floor using a boroscope

Tags: structural, pest-control

Just treated for termites as they were coming up through the floorboards by the back door, and I wanted to check the existing wood since I've noticed some sagging floorboards.

I can cut into the drywall ceilings or I can use a boroscope.  When using the boroscope, what should I be looking for in terms of damage, since I wouldn't be able to prod the beams or wood with a stick or awl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A horoscope will do you no good here but a borescope may, or may not depending on the severity of the damage.

Generally the best you can see with a borescope is EVIDENCE.  Wood debris in the area below the infestation, mud tubes between the ground and the wood, possibly some areas in wood where chunks have fallen off.  But seeing direct termite damage is iffy.

The problem is that they enter through very small holes, which may not be in a visible area and eat away from the inside.  They generally don't penetrate to the outside to protect themselves and so the wood piece can look perfectly fine from the outside and be riddled with damage on the inside.

Usually you use a "poking" tool to check for such damage although cutting will expose the damage as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - changed "horoscope" back to "horoscope"... Dang this autocorrect

Comment: Hey, Mister Spell Check: "They generally don't penetrate to the _output_ to protect themselves...". :D LOL... (I _hate it_ when that happens) Yes, I could edit it myself, but it's much more fun this way. ;)